# Why got 404 for API endpoint with react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, api, go, cors, go-gin

## Created backend API use `gin` with `go` language

```
type Post struct {
    ID uint `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
}

func main() {
    // ...
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/posts", GetPosts)
    r.GET("/posts/:id", GetPost)
    r.POST("/posts", CreatePost)
    r.PUT("/posts/:id", UpdatePost)
    r.DELETE("/posts/:id", DeletePost)

    r.Run(":8080")
}

func GetPosts(c *gin.Context) {
    var posts []Post
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    if err := db.Find(&posts).Error; err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatus(404)
            fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
            c.JSON(200, post)
    }
}

// ...
```

## Created frontend use `react` with `react-admin`

### src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { PostList } from './posts';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:8080');

const App = () => (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
        </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

### src/posts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField } from 'react-admin';

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
            <TextField source="body" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

When access `http://localhost:3000` from chrome browser, got `Failed to fetch` message. From the console I saw:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/posts?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have tried to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the go API program, but the same result. From the `gin` output I got:

```
[GIN] 2018/06/12 - 18:14:50 | 404 |       1.813µs |       127.0.0.1 | OPTIONS  /posts?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

---

## Add

Added `cors` package then change source as:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        // ...
)

// ...

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
            AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:8080"},
    }))

    r.GET("/posts", GetPosts)
    r.GET("/posts/:id", GetPost)
    r.POST("/posts", CreatePost)
    r.PUT("/posts/:id", UpdatePost)
    r.DELETE("/posts/:id", DeletePost)

    r.Run()
}
```

Got same error again:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/posts?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This time, the output of `gin` was:

```
[GIN] 2018/06/13 - 11:01:59 | 403 |       7.873µs |             ::1 | OPTIONS  /posts?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

Comment: Try to add `CORS` middleware of gin for golang code to allow access to cross domain requests

Comment: @Himanshu I have added a middleware but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works:

```
func main() {
        // ...
        r := gin.Default()
        r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
                AllowOrigins:  []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
                AllowMethods:  []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD"},
                AllowHeaders:  []string{"Origin", "Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
                ExposeHeaders: []string{"X-Total-Count"},
        }))
        r.GET("/posts", GetPosts)
        // ...
        r.Run()
}

func GetPosts(c *gin.Context) {
        var posts []Post
        if err := db.Find(&posts).Error; err != nil {
                c.AbortWithStatus(404)
                fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
                c.Header("X-Total-Count", "25")
                c.JSON(200, posts)
        }
}
```

Due to [ra-data-json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-json-server).

Answer (score 1):

Add `CORS` middleware for cross origin domain requests. I would prefer to hit the api using `postman` to check if it is working fine. Below is the way to implement `CORS` middleware for gin in go:-

```
package main

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    // CORS for http://localhost:8080 and https://github.com origins, allowing:
    // - PUT and PATCH methods
    // - Origin header
    // - Credentials share
    // - Preflight requests cached for 12 hours
    router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:8080, https://localhost:8080"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "HEAD", "PUT", "PATCH"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
    }))
    router.Run()
}
```

**Edited:** For allowing all origins use `Default` config for `cors` as

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    // same as
    // config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    // config.AllowAllOrigins = true
    // router.Use(cors.New(config))
    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Run()
}
```

For more information checkout [CORS middleware](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) for gin

Comment: Thank you. I have added that package. But the same result again. I have added the source to the question.

Comment: You need to set AllowOrigins("http://localhost:8080") & AllowMethods & AllowHeaders("Origin")

Comment: If set `localhost:8080` will cause `panic: bad origin: origins must either be '*' or include http:// or https://` error when start server.

Comment: @vv I have edited the answer for allowing all origins you can use `Default` config. Please check edited answer

Comment: @Himanshu Thank you. This time got `Warning: Missing translation for key: "The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?"` I also added `X-Total-Count` but didn't fix.

Comment: @vv Have you checked the link for more information. Also set the headers it requires Because when you are requesting from different domain you should add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, I add this line to `cors.Config`: `ExposeHeaders: []string{"X-Total-Count"},`, and this line for adding header: `AllowHeaders:  []string{"Content-Type"},`. Not work.